# Selecting row in SSMS causes Entity Framework 4 to Fail

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

I have a simple Entity Framework 4 unit test that creates a new record, saves it, attempts to find it, then deletes it.  All works great, unless...

... I open up SQL Server Management Studio while stopped at a breakpoint in the unit test and execute a SELECT statement that returns the row I just created (*not* SELECT FOR UPDATE, not WITH (updlock), no transaction, just a plain SELECT).

If I do that before attempting to find the row I just created, I don't find the row.  If I instead do that after finding the row but before deleting the row, I do find the row but get an OptimisticConcurrencyException.

This is consistently repeatable.

Unit Test:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void CreateFindDeleteActiveParticipantsTest()
{
    // Setup this test
    Participant utPart = CreateUTParticipant();

    ctx.Participants.AddObject(utPart);
    ctx.SaveChanges();

    // External SELECT Point #1:
    // part is null

    // Find participant
    Participant part = ParticipantRepository.Find(UT_SURVEY_ID, UT_TOKEN);
    Assert.IsNotNull(part, "Expected to find a participant");

    // External SELECT Point #2: 
    // SaveChanges throws OptimisticConcurrencyException

    // Cleanup this test
    ctx.Participants.DeleteObject(utPart);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you have a test like this? It mostly tests the Entity Framework itself, which Microsoft will thoroughly test for you. And it also has a database dependency, which is bad in many ways.

Comment: @Matt: First off, the test failed so probably good that I had it.  But mostly that was the setup and tear down of a more complex test.  I distilled down the full test for SO.

Comment: @Eric: Fair enough. I was being honest with the question, not sarcastic.

Comment: IMHO: This sounds like a SQL Server issue, not an EF issue. Profile what the EF is doing, and reproduce it with two copies of SSMS.

Comment: @Matt: Didn't mean to imply you were being sarcastic :-) My intent with the test is really to prove that EF works as I expect it to, especially since I have encountered a lot of weirdness with it since starting to dig in for the past week.

Comment: @Craig: Could be SQL Server.  I'll add that tag in case a SQL Server guru has seen that behavior.  Will profile but won't have a chance to do that until tonight.  Still, if this type of behavior happened with non-EF CRUD patterns it would probably have been noticed as a glaring issue long ago.

Comment: I *do* see some of these issues in SQL Server when not using RLV: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179599.aspx